# Python: Nested while loop will 'continue' from the first while, not the nested while

Tags: python, windows, loops, iteration, continue

I have a nested `while` statement, and inside the second statement I have a `try` block. In the `except` block I have some code and then `continue`. The problem is when it hits that `continue` it will start from the **first** `while`, and not the expected nested `while`.

I've been searching for a bit, but I'm not sure if it's intended behavior?

```py
while iRowCount < iMaxRows:
    # ...
    # Code here for getting information from a database
    # ...

    print("Iterating")
    while i2RowCount < i2MaxRows:
        try:
            readUrl = "someURL" # This is assigned from the database
            BrowserObj.get(readUrl) # Using Webdriver to navigate to the URL

            elem = BrowserObj.find_element_by_link_text("Find Me")
            elemHref = elem.get_attribute('href')
            BrowserObj.get(elemHref) # Navigate to new link found

            # This is never reached 
            theOutput = BrowserObj.find_element_by_css_selector(".classNames.here")
            print("Out: " + str(theOutput))
            exit()

        except NoSuchElementException as E:
            print("Not found. (Iteration: #" + str(i2RowCount) + ")")
            i2RowCount += 1
            continue

        i2RowCount += 1
    iRowCount += 1
```

The exception will throw at `elem = BrowserObj.find_element_by_link_text("Find Me")`. But my output will be the following:

```
Iterating
Not found. (Iteration: #0)
Iterating
Not found. (Iteration: #0)
Iterating
Not found. (Iteration: #0)
Iterating
Not found. (Iteration: #0)
Iterating
Not found. (Iteration: #0)
...this will keep going.
```

So for some reason the `continue` seems to be going back to my first loop, and not my nested one as intended... Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code has several undefined symbols, and is missing set-up code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating this and wasn't able to. Please try and post a code snippet which can be run and shows this bug.

This is my more generic version of this that I quickly wrote which doesn't seem to recreate this issue:

```
i = 0
j = 0


while i < 10:
    print(f'OUTER LOOP: {i}')
    i += 1
    while j < 10:
        print(f'INNER LOOP: {j}')
        try:
            j += 1
            raise Exception("CRASHING!")
        except:
            print("CATCHING")
            continue
```

Output:

```
OUTER LOOP: 0
INNER LOOP: 0
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 1
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 2
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 3
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 4
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 5
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 6
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 7
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 8
CATCHING
INNER LOOP: 9
CATCHING
OUTER LOOP: 1
OUTER LOOP: 2
OUTER LOOP: 3
OUTER LOOP: 4
OUTER LOOP: 5
OUTER LOOP: 6
OUTER LOOP: 7
OUTER LOOP: 8
OUTER LOOP: 9
```

As you can see the continue appears to only be impacting the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a one-off issue...I'm still unclear as to why it was happening but it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: this answer probably should be a comment to your original question.